# wordpress capabilities

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out whether wordpress can handle the following requirements for a site:

1. incorporating yahoo weather api (and other widgets etc)
2. testimonial page (user inputs, which have to be moderated back-end and approved)
3. image gallery (with back-end manager)
4. video gallery (basically youtube video links - with backend manager)
5. extremely custom design

I know WP is powerful, but can it handle these requirements? How easy/difficult is it to integrate plugins to handle this functionality?

Thanks.

PS. I know this is not a programming question per se, but there are several such "capabilities" questions on the stack!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes WordPress would allow you to do all of the above.

1. You would have to implement this yourself as a plugin. There maybe a plugin already available. This link should help you get started, http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/03/yahoo-weather-api/
2. The commenting system would easily allow you to do this
3. There are heaps of galleries, try [nextgen](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) gallery, works great.
4. You could easily provide an admin panel which would allow users to paste the youtube video code in. See the WP docs. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page and http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus
5. WP allows custom themes and they are fairly easy to construct with a little programming knowledge. Simply searching on Google will find you a abundance of walk through tutorials.